# Normalization should I make two tables for this schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have read about normalization and now want you to ask should I have 2 tables for it or is one enough.

I have a object like this:

```
        {
            "name": "Farbe",
            "id": 11087368061250,
            "product_id": 8812906250562,
            "position": 1,
            "values": [
                "schwarz",
                "gelb",
                "blau",
                "rot",
                "weiß",
                "lila"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Größe",
            "id": 11087368061250,
            "product_id": 8812906250562,
            "position": 1,
            "values": [
                "22",
                "23",
                "24",
                "25",
                "26",
                "27"
            ]
        },
```

I want to put this in my db so I have 2 options. All in one table or two.

Option1:

```
CREATE TABLE product_options (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  p_id UUID REFERENCES product(id),
  name VARCHAR,
  position SMALLINT,
  value VARCHAR
)
```

Option 2 (With two tables)

```
CREATE TABLE product_options (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  p_id UUID REFERENCES product(id),
  name VARCHAR,
  position SMALLINT
)

CREATE TABLE product_options_value (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  produt_options_id UUID REFERENCES product_options(id),
  value VARCHAR
)
```

So what would you prefer and which is better ? I hope you can explain me which one would be better because I am new in sql

Comment: This looks like the EAV anti-pattern: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios

Comment: Size and color are two very different items, and should imho not be stored in the same table. A table with colors and another table with sizes, makes sense. I would try to avoid the EAV anti-pattern

Comment: @FrankHeikens , the user can name a option whatever he wants. He can use 3 options, and create a option name whatever he want to use. Maybe Colors or Maybe Length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be two things: the property itself with all its possible values (which would look like your option 2) and the actual property of a product (with a single value). I would model the former like this:

```
CREATE TABLE option (
  id big GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE option_value (
  option_id bigint REFERENCES product_options,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (options_id, value)
);
```

The association to an actual product would be

```
CREATE TABLE product_option (
  product_id bigint REFERENCES product NOT NULL,
  option_id bigint NOT NULL,
  value text NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (option_id, value) REFERENCES option_value
);
```

I chose not to add an artificial primary key to `option_value`, which means that both `option_id` and `value` need to be in `product_option`. If `value` is a long string, using an artificial primary key might be the better way, in order to avoid duplicating the long string.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, but why you have 2x value ? One in option_value and one in product_option, so the value in product_option could be removed because I already have the value in option_value

Comment: You need it for the foreign key. If you don't like that, you can add an artificial primary key to `option_value` and reference that.